# Open a MHT file inside of Webview

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, urlsession

Im trying to open a MHT file inside of Webview, when I load the page presents like no rendered.
Can I load some how or convert to html to load with webview ?

To give a idea I need to load my cookies to download a file.mht to present when the internet go´s down.

[The file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDnzb.jpg)

```
func downloadHTML(for url: URL, cookies: [HTTPCookie], completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let headers = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies)
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completion(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  let data = data,
                  httpResponse.statusCode == 200
            else {
                completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "Invalid response", code: 0, userInfo: nil)))
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let documentsDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
                let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("page.mht")
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
                    do {
                        try data.write(to: fileURL)
                        completion(.success(fileURL))
                    } catch {
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How can a bot know if a question is specific or not? This is no doubt a specific and good question. @Community